# Django ckeditor with wordcount

Tags: django, ckeditor, ckeditor-wordcount

Does anyone know how to integrate this [wordcount plugin](http://www.n7studios.co.uk/2010/03/01/ckeditor-word-count-plugin/) with the existing django-ckeditor apps? Either https://github.com/dwaiter/django-ckeditor or https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/.

Specifically, I'm stuck at Step 4

> For your CKEditor instance, use the following HTML markup (`content` can be any element name you wish, so long as the hidden field has its element name in the format `elementWordCount`)

```
<label for="content">Content</label>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content"></textarea>
<input name="contentWordCount" type="hidden" value="250" />
```

Where do I insert that `Input` element?

I'm using the widget btw.

Alternative solutions to having a wordcount plugin are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/. 
I've just updated the repo to support widget template customization.

You should now be able to integrate the wordcount plugin by specifying it as part of the `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` setting:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'extraPlugins': 'wordcount',
    }
}
```

and then overriding the `ckeditor/widget.html` template to look like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input name="contentWordCount" type="hidden" value="250" />

<textarea{{ final_attrs|safe }}>{{ value }}</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace("{{ id }}", {{ config|safe }});
</script>
```

*I've loaded jQuery here through Google APIs just as an example.*

Comment: Sweet. Will try it out and get back to you!

Comment: So I've included the wordcount plugin and I see the wordcount at the bottom right. But I am not able to see the element `<input name="contentWordCount" type="hidden" value="250" />` on my page source when I updated `ckeditor/widget.html`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I had to change `content` in `contentWordCount` to `<id attribute of text area field>WordCount`. Changing the value to the `name` or `class` attribute didn't do it for me.